# Adding data to existing mongodb document using SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

Scenario: I have a existing document which have 3 fields now : requestId , username , comment. There are 3 level of users suppose employe , team lead , manager . When anyone comments the username and comment should be added to the existing document . Currently I am using MongodbRepository and played around save() and insert() , they only update or insert the document . I also found that if we could upsert using any query however I could not found anything.

Also I found that one of the way is to use $Set , but how can I use it with mondbRepository ?